# Cursor moves one position left after exiting insert mode?

Tags: evil, spacemacs

I'm using `evil` via `spacemacs`.  When I exit insert state, the cursor moves to the left one character.  Why is that?  Is it a bug, or is it a feature?  Can I turn it off?

Comment: Today I realized that `evil-normal-state` and `evil-force-normal-state` is behaving different than each other. 

While `(setq evil-move-cursor-back t)` in my configuration using `evil-normal-state` moves the cursor back but `evil-force-normal-state` does not move the cursor back. I don't know did they do especially or is this kind of bug but I am using this feature :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Moving one space left after leaving insert" is the default behavior in Vim, which `evil` (on top of which `spacemacs` is built) emulates by default.  If you don't like that behavior, you can set `(setq evil-move-cursor-back nil)`.

Comment: Thank you! Now i see what a dumb question it was. I've checked my `.vimrc`, and it there is a `inoremap <Tab> <Esc>\`^` (i remap `Esc` to `Tab`). That's why i've never noticed it in Vim!

Comment: I use Doom Emacs, this variable when set to `nil` works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, especially after spaces. I wonder whether it is the same in `spacemacs`. Actually, looking another post I realised that it doesn't work for append `a` and `o` commands. I would have thought that it should.